# Как создать ассоциации в sequelizeJs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

есть 2 таблицы, с пользователями и объявлениями. Хочу сделать связь, чтобы при получении всех объявлений получать и данные того кто создал объявление.

В таком виде как есть при создании второго объявления вылазит ошибка:

```
SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table "ads" violates foreign key constraint "ads_id_fkey"
```

Вот такие модели:

```
    const users_panel = sequelize.define('users_panel', {
    email:  { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING, 
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    }
})
const ads = sequelize.define('ads', {
    user_panel_id: { 
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

})
usersPanel.hasMany(ads, {foreignKey: 'user_panel_id', as: 'ads'});
ads.belongsTo(usersPanel, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'user'});

sequelize.sync({force: false})
.then(data => console.log('ok'))
.catch(error => console.error(error))


const users_panel = sequelize.define('users_panel', {
    email:  { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING, 
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    }
})

const ads = sequelize.define('ads', {
    user_panel_id: { 
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

})
usersPanel.hasMany(ads, {foreignKey: 'user_panel_id', as: 'ads'});
ads.belongsTo(usersPanel, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'user'});

sequelize.sync({force: false})
.then(data => console.log('ok'))
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

А вот так создаю и получаю объявления:

```
ads.create(dataCreate)


ads.findAndCountAll({
            where: search,
            limit: 100,
            offset: 0,
            include: [{
                as: 'user',
                model: usersPanel
            }]
        })
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,  может есть хорошая статья в которой описывается как создавать связи, уже 2 ([один](https://toster.ru/q/547235) и [два](https://toster.ru/q/547235)) вопроса создавал по  поводу связей таблиц, а ответы не смог получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к модели `ads` :

```
user_panel_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      foreignKey : true
}
```

Ассоциации:

```
users_panel.hasMany(ads, {foreignKey: 'user_panel_id'})
ads.belongsTo(users_panel, {foreignKey : 'user_panel_id'})
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Можно уточнить, если бы я только написал users_panel.hasMany(ads, {foreignKey: 'user_panel_id'}) это было бы ошибкой, всегда нужно связь делать с двух сторон?

Comment: @Jenya7771 Полагаю смотря для чего вы делаете `include` при получении данных модели. Не пробовал такое, поэтому точно ответить не могу.

Comment: а если у меня не одно значение id в поле user_panel_id будет, а массив Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER) , как тогда сделать связь что бы получить всех пользователей из массива?

Comment: @Jenya7771 Это зависит от того какую СУБД вы прогоняете через ORM, некоторые такое вообще не поддерживают, если такое делать, то лучше самому реализовать связь и не делать массив внешним ключом, но это очень не эффективно и может вызвать несогласованность данных.

Comment: Я использую postgresql. Получается лучше сделать отдельную таблицу, с массивом ключей не получится?

Comment: @Jenya7771, Postgresql точно не поддерживает, поэтому да

Comment: Можете подсказать, как работать с таблицей связкой? Я создал связку, но как сделать create не могу понять.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860455/Как-сделать-create-belongstomany-sequelizejs