# Как сделать create belongsToMany sequelizeJs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

есть 2 таблицы, с категориями и объявлениями:

```
const ads = sequelize.define('ads', {
  name: { 
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  categories: { 
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
    allowNull: false
  },
})

const categories = sequelize.define('categories', {
      name: { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
    })
```

Я связал их вот так:

```
ads.belongsToMany(categories, { as: 'adsCategories', through: 'ads_categories'})
categories.belongsToMany(ads, { as: 'categoriesAds', through: 'ads_categories'})
```

И у меня возник вопрос, как мне при создании объявления, в таблицу связку вставить несколько категорий для него?

```
    ads.create({
        name: 'name'
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: а не `ads.hasMany` ?

Comment: Не понял, имеете ввиду ads.hasMany(categories, { as: 'adsCategories', through: 'ads_categories'})
categories.belongsToMany(ads, { as: 'categoriesAds', through: 'ads_categories'})

Comment: Ну да, у вас ведь объявление имеет много категорий или я не прав ?

Comment: И такой вопрос, массив категорий INT, это ИД категорий ?

Comment: Да, объявление имеет много категорий. Массив это старое поле, я думал можно сделать связку таблиц не делая отдельную таблицу для связки, но как понял так нельзя сделать.

Comment: ads.hasMany(categories, { as: 'adsCategories', through: 'ads_categories'})
categories.belongsToMany(ads, { as: 'categoriesAds', through: 'ads_categories'}).  В таком виде ошибка получается "N:M associations are not supported with hasMany. Use belongsToMany instead
    at new HasMany"

Comment: Потому что необходимо указать внешний ключ, которого у вас вообще нет.

Comment: Внешний ключ категории в таблице с объявлениями?